# virtualbox missing add "host-only network" option

Tags: virtualbox

Running Virtual Box in:
Host Mac High Sierra
Guess Windows 7

I am trying to connect from the Host to guess following several tutorials which involve create a "**host-only networks**" on the Virtual Box

However, I cannot see the option to add  "Host-only networks" in the settings, only NAT networks. See attached picture

I would appreciate if anyone could help me

[VM network settings ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUAJM.png)

Answer (score 22):

I was having the same issue with the new version and found this solution.
Instead of going from: **File**->**Preferences**-> **Networks** you can do that directly from: **File**->**Host Network Manager**. From there you will be able to create a host-only network as usual.

Comment: I don't have that option either.I have something called 'Network Operations Manager', which on click just says, "There are no active network operations". What version virtualbox you are using ? I am using the latest one as of today.